# Properly Centering an Image (Margin Auto?)

Tags: html, css, mobile, position

I need to center a logo above a content box, with center alignment.

At present, I use the following code:

```
#logo img {
margin: -12em 0 4em 17em;
}
```

Although this works on computers, it breaks on mobile phones. See screenshot.

How can I get the functionality I desire on both platforms? I tried `margin: 0px auto;` to no avail.

URL: http://ec2-174-129-169-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

[image: iPhone Preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the image centered? Then why is `#logo` set to `float: left;` in layout.css line 89?

Comment: Also a solution: `float:none !important;` if you don't want to overwrite your layout file.

Comment: @TrentScott: Just tested it and same problem. It seems like !important doesn't even prioritize the float. Either change the layout file, or restructure the HTML so that your logo isn't inside #logo.. a bit weird.

Comment: @TrentScott: Well you can have your layout.css file, and a index.css file and overwrite the #logo div with !important, but you cannot specify your logo img with important as it wont propagate to parents elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove float: left from #logo and then go to #logo img and add:

```
#logo img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't edit the `float: left;` because it would break a compatibility with a template engine. Added the following: http://pastie.org/4332446. But, it still doesn't work. Thoughts?